# Schengen Visa Multiple Entry Query

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, multiple-entry

I was issued a Schengen visa by Switzerland in 2022. I went for a visit for 10 days and had a pleasant time. Now I am planning to visit France this year in June, 2023.

I checked my schengen visa that was issued by Switzerland and it says  Au Bis Until (guessing "valid until") March 15, 2024 and Number of Entries says MULT. Duration of Stay is 90 days. Valid for "Etats Schengen".

Does this mean that I do not need to apply for a Schengen visa again and I can use the schengen visa issued in 2022 by Switzerland to visit France?

Any information will be highly appreciated.

Comment: As long as the visa is valid, it can be used to enter the Schengen area. See the link above for the answer to your question

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica That is not correct. 90 days means **90 days in every 180 day period** which with a multiple entry visa valid for 2 years can be more than 90 days (4 180 day periods)

Comment: Yes, with a multiple entry visa you can enter the Schengen Area more than once. Only on the **first** visit are you required to visit the country that issued the visa (as your main destination given in the original application). In your case you are not required to visit Switzerland during your next trip.

Comment: Thank you all for your prompt response to this. Negates a lot of headache. appreciate your input in this matter

Comment: "au" and "bis" mean "until" in French and German, respectively.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Mark Johnson is correct.  However, if the number given is less than 90 then the limit applies over the life of the visa.

Comment: Thanks to all for the correction. I've deleted my comment.

Comment: See also https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/how-read-visa-sticker_en

Comment: @Traveller That page is, however, misleading since it doesn't take into account the case of visas with a long-term validity as done here: [Details on visa - Federal Foreign Office - How to check the information contained in a type C (short stay) visa](https://uk.diplo.de/uk-en/02/visa/details-on-visa/2538208): *If you have been granted a visa with long-term validity (e.g. between 6 months and 5 years), the entry in this field indicates the number of days you may spend in the Schengen area within a period of 180 days.*